# How to open a page in serenity with default filter?

Tags: c#

I have an page, Companies and in this page i have one button to Users.

When i click on this button it should go to Users page, filtered by this company,
how i set this filter in the users page ?

This is my Companies page:

[image]

I already opening the Users page but i need to set this SQL for this page:

```
SELET * FROM USERS WHERE COMPANYID = 1;
```

This is my Button and action button on Grid:

```
protected getColumns(): Slick.Column[] {
            var columns = super.getColumns();
            columns.push(
                {
                    field: "Ações",
                    name: "Ações",
                    format: ctx => {
                        return "<a class='inline-action usuario-row' title='Usuários'></a>";
                    },
                    width: 50,
                    minWidth: 24,
                    maxWidth: 50
                });

            return columns;
        }

        protected onClick(e: JQueryEventObject, row: number, cell: number): void {
            super.onClick(e, row, cell);

            let item = this.itemAt(row);

            if ($(e.target).hasClass('usuario-row')) {
                window.location.href = '/Cadastros/EmpresasUsuarios?empresaId=' + item.EmpresaId;
            }
        }
```

So, how i set this sql on new page?